# Affixing a plastic A4 foil to a (textured) wall

Tags: walls

I have an A4 sheet of paper inside of a standard (plastic) protective foil/lamination. I would like to affix this sheet onto an external wall, as a public sign/notice. The surface of the wall is not smooth but rather a bit uneven/textured.

I am wondering what kind of substance to use to make the foil stick to the wall. I guess some type of playdough should do the trick, either the type for children, or maybe some special type used in constructions. But I am not sure which type to buy.

I would like this to adhere well between the plastic foil and the wall, but also be undoable, for when I will want to later remove the notice; but for it to withstand weather elements (rain etc).

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

My short list would be:

1. 3M Command strips
2. Blue tack / "poster putty"
3. Double-sided foam tape